# Cart only quantity editable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a shopping cart ,in my show cart page I'm trying to give user flexibility to update the quantity and I want only one quantity field to be editable.
Here is my code

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product 
  belongs_to :cart
  #before_save :quantity
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :line_items
```

**In my View**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<table>
<tr>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Unit Price </th>
    <th> Quantity </th>
    <th>  Price </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

  <%= render :partial => 'line_item' %>

 </table>
<span> Total </span><%= number_to_currency(Cart.get_total(session[:cart_id])) %>
```

**Partial View**

```
  <%  @lineitem.each do |item| %>
   <tr>
<td><%= item.id %>
    <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
   <td><%= number_to_currency(item.product.price) %></td>
     <td><%= item.quantity %></td>(Make this editable with update button)
    <td><%= number_to_currency(LineItem.get_price(item.id,item.product.price)) 
      %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Remove', item , confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete  %></td>
        </tr>

         <% end %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_line_item_path %>


      **Thanks for the reply,**                                              

      <%  @line_item.each do |item| %>
     <tr>
<td><%= item.id %>
    <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(item.product.price) %></td>
    <td><%= form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br />
    <%= f.number_field  :quantity %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
 </td>
   <td><%=      number_to_currency(LineItem.get_price(item.id,item.product.price)) 
   %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove', item , confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete  %></td>
    </tr>

       <% end %>
```

How do I make item.quantity editable where as all others being readonly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure you actually ask a question as @nathanvda points out.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity
```

protects all your attributes from mass-assignment except `cart_id`, `product_id` and `quantity`. This means that other attributes won't be editable unless you set them independently. If you want to allow other attributes to be editable you must add them to this line.

@nathanvda and @simonmorley are right. You need to make sure you ask a question and take the time to make it understandable by others who might help you.

Comment: Can anyone help in answering above question